# Sql Query to get system current time

Tags: sql-server

Lets say Machine A is app server where I am running sql query.
Machine B where sqlserver is setup. They are in different time zone. eg Machine A is in IST and Machine B in CST
Now I want to run sql query in Machine A to get its current time rather than sql server current time.

For eg. I tried all these functions but they return Machine B(sql server current time)
            SELECT SYSDATETIME()
    ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ,GETDATE()

I can fetch Machine A current time by Java and pass it to sql query but is there any way to fetch by sql query itself??

Comment: why would the sql server know what the time is on a remote computer?

Comment: In a particular query i need system time to fetch records accordingly.

Comment: my question was rhetorical. if you want to store the local time of a remote computer on your database, add it as a parameter to your sql script or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. And it makes sense because SQL will send your command to the server. As such - you expect the SQL Server to then magically go to your machine and execute code?

The general approach is that all local processing (app server level) is finished when the SQL gets sent to the server (as a string).

Also good coding standards would ask you what you care (outside of clocks not being in sync) as all application internal timestamps are in UTC anyway (regardless of timezone of the server) and the timezone conversion is only done on the UI level code.

So, no - what you want can not be done, and in most applications is not needed as they handle the problem outside the database.

Comment: Thanks Guys. seems like its doesn't make sense to query App server time. Better i supply through Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the DateTime Class tools of other languages.

You don't query from a Database the Current Time because it is not a stored data, or a storable ones.

There is no solution if you do it in the SQL, you really have to do it in a language like Java or C# because they have access to the Time of the machine, since the program is intended to run in a machine, therefore they have acess to it.